# TableLayout's not receiving background if i use HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying use HorizontalScrollView to scroll my TableLayout horizontally, but if i set HorizontalScrollView, the background in TableLayout and TableRow don't work.

I try set ScrollView and all work fine.

Somebody can help me? I don't understand what's happening.

XML bellow:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_start_screen"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
            </TableLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_deny_state"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:onClick="closescreen"
                android:text="Close" />

        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

img of the error below:

With ScrollView:
http://s11.postimg.org/k9hg1a79v/Screenshot_2015_02_19_15_43_56.png

With HorizontalScrollView:
http://s4.postimg.org/iprnwxg65/2015_02_19_15_41_14.png

Comment: setbackground to your linear layout.

Comment: The error continue, the problem is the background of the TableLayout, TableRow and the button. but if i don't usa HorizontalScrollView it work fine.

Comment: then why you don't use scrollview instead of horizontal one.

Comment: because is a table with much information, i need of the horizontal scroll to access all information

Comment: android:fillViewport="true"  , try this in horizontal scrollview

Comment: same problem, not work

Comment: I tried change the width of tablelayout and button and with number width, that's work, example width:"400 dp" but with match_parent, wrap_content or fill_parent do this error

Comment: change width of scrollview to fillparent

Comment: just try changing width height it will work.

Comment: change fillparent width of scrollview and linera layout to wrapcontent.and try

Comment: not work, same problem

Comment: then why don't you put your rows one below another using scrollview if this is not working.